# Is there a way of printing my clickCount in stead of using the <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, count, counter

Is there a way of printing my clickCount to the page without using an input element?

Here is my code for a better understanding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Vote!</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function countClicks() {
var x = 0;


x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;

var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
if(x>=clickLimit) {

            }
else
{
    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks();" /><br>
<input id="counting" type="text">



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is an insert tag? Where is the insert tag?

Comment: Well, I read your code. I can't say that I now have a better understanding of anything.

Comment: I think the OP meant the input tag where they're displaying the value of their x variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your value into any element.

Given your current code, replacing your `input` with a `div` and using `innerHTML` instead of `value` will work.

```
document.getElementById( "counting" ).innerHTML = x;

<div id="counting"></div>
```

Might I also point you in the direction of [jQuery](http://jquery.com). This will make your life a lot easier whilst working with Javascript.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JfRwY/).

Comment: I made a typeo. It's actually innerHTML not innerHtml